# where is my memory in linux?

Tags: linux, memory, debian, ram

i try to find where my memory:

i use program [mema.py](https://github.com/acrixl/bug-free-memory/blob/master/mema.py)
which sum memory usage by processes (ps aux --sort -rss)
according program 22% (3713500 kb) memory used by programs (i get 16Gb RAM )

**free** reports:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      16431416   14773344    1658072     440524     234416    1780688
-/+ buffers/cache:   12758240    3673176
Swap:     43528916          0   43528916
```

(14773344 kb used total) - (1780688 cached) - (234416 cached buffers) - (3713500 app) = 9044740

so where 9Gb ? For what and what they are used for?

debian 8.8
Linux acrhlx 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.43-2 (2017-04-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux

**Update**
i found my memory
it consumed by ZFS
it not reported in buffers+cached, not sure bug it or feature
[more about zfs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601520/zfs-always-out-of-memory)

Answer (score 1):

Used does not mean what you think it means; used includes memory that is in use but can be made available (i.e. is not currently used by applications). For details read [this](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/).

Further, I do not believe that `ps aux --sort -rss` will show everything. I cannot see the kernel in there for instance (see `cat /proc/meminfo|grep Slab`) ... or the kernel modules (see the second column of `cat /proc/modules`). For details see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/97265/199642) on [Unix & Linux Stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com) which incidentally is where this question actually belongs in my opinion.

Comment: i know about Used column, kernel slab accounted in Buffers + Cached columns, i take it in account, i too not believe in ps aux, but what to use to get information about 9Gb of RAM, for what and what they are used for?

Answer (score 0):

ZFS module not reported in buffers+cached

i update my memory analyser tool that help to find problems like that

[bug-free-memory](https://github.com/acrixl/bug-free-memory)