# The structure of /proc/kcore on 64-bit machine and relation to physical memory

Tags: linux, memory, 64bit, gdb

Let me preface this question by saying that I've found a lot of answers for questions similar to my question but for 32-bit machines. However, I can't find anything for 64-bit machines. Please no answers with respect to 32-bit machines.

According to many sources on Stack Exchange, `/proc/kcore` can be literally dumped (e.g., with `dd`) to a file in order to get a copy of physical memory... But this clearly does not work for a 64-bit machine, for which `/proc/kcore` is 128TB in size.

As an aside, I note that it is possible to access only the first MB of memory through `/dev/mem`. This is for security reasons. Getting around this involves recompiling the kernel, which I don't want to do... nor can I do for my purposes (I have to work with the running kernel).

Ok... so, `/proc/kcore` is an ELF-core file dump of the physical memory and it can be viewed using `gdb`. For example, with:

```
gdb /usr/[blah]/vmlinux /proc/kcore
```

This I *can* do... but, this is *not* what I want to do. I would like to export the physical memory to a file for offline analysis. But I'm running into issues.

For one thing, I can't just dump `/proc/kcore` to a file since it's 128TB.  I want to dump all of physical memory, but I don't know *where* it is in `/proc/kcore`. I only see non-zero data up until byte 3600 and then it's all zeros for as far as I have looked (about 40GB). I think this may have to do with how the memory is mapped to `/proc/kcore`, but I don't understand the structure and need some guidance.

More stuff I think I know: I know that only 48 bits are used for addressing, not 64 bits. This implies that there should be 2<sup>48</sup>=256TB of memory available... but `/proc/kcore` is only 128TB, which is *I think* because addressing is further divided into a chunk from 0x0000000000000000 to 0x00007fffffffffff (128TB) and a chunk from 0xffff800000000000 to 0xffffffffffffffff (128TB). So, somehow this makes `/proc/kcore` 128TB... but is this because one of these chunks is mapped to `/proc/kcore` and one isn't? Or some other reason?

So, as an example, I can use `gdb` to analyze `/proc/kcore` and find, e.g., the location (?) of the sys_call_table:

```
(gdb) p (unsigned long*) sys_call_table
$1 = (unsigned long *) 0xffffffff811a4f20 <sys_read>
```

Does this mean that the chunk of memory from 0xffff8000000000000 to 0xffffffffffffffff is what is in `/proc/kcore`? And if so, how is this mapped to `/proc/kcore`? For example using

```
dd if=/proc/kcore bs=1 skip=2128982200 count=100 | xxd
```

shows only zeros (2128982200 is a little before 0xffffffffffffffff-0xffffffff811a4f20)...

Furthermore, I know how to use `gcore` to dump the memory of a given process for analysis. And I also know that I can look in `/proc/PID/maps` to see what process memory looks like... but *nevertheless* I still have no idea how to dump the whole physical memory... and it's kind of driving me nuts. Please help me avoid going crazy... ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot more searching I think I have convinced myself that there is no simple way to get what I want.

So, what did I end up doing? I installed LiME from github (https://github.com/504ensicsLabs/LiME)

```
git clone https://github.com/504ensicsLabs/LiMe
cd /LiME/src
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=$PWD modules
```

The above commands create the lime.ko kernel module. A full dump of memory can be obtained by then running:

```
insmod ./lime.ko "path=/root/temp/outputDump.bin format=raw dio=0"
```

which just inserts the kernel module and the string are the parameters specifying the output file location and format... AND IT WORKED! YAY.

Comment: Now I can run that command on your computer and see all your passwords or secret unicorns or whatever. Maybe a security risk for production machines ?

Comment: This may also be helpful: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119762/how-to-dump-memory-image-from-linux-system

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look to the output of this command `sudo readelf -e -g -t /proc/kcore`. You can have the offset for every virtual address space, and then dump it by lseek() and read().

It cost to me a lot to discover this. First I thought it was virtual address mapping read-only. Like /dev/kmem but without write permissions... and when I read it's a pseudo ELF file with the RAM access, which can be accessed with ELF binary utils, I tried readelf.

So, fine.